# Good techniques for serving several images per page

Tags: image, performance, cdn, download-speed

I have a web application that needs to serve a large amount of small images per page (up to 100). I can use caching to reduce calls to the database/backend, but there is a noticeable impact from having to make so many separate requests for the images themselves, as the images take some time to request and render, especially on slower connections.

What good practices exist for serving several images on a page? I'm aware of using a CDN (e.g. S3 + Cloudfront) to reduce bottlenecking on http requests and serve content from a closer geographical location, as well as potentially loading images/content via Ajax only once they come to the user's view in the browser. Are there other techniques that might provide significant performance gains for image-heavy pages? It doesn't really matter whether they relate to hardware, frontend or something else.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the images of? Are they related? That is, when you show one, do you always show the same bunch of of others?

Comment: @Oded: The images are all different, generally small jpegs around 10-20kb each.

Comment: The question is more of if they are used together commonly.

Comment: @Oded - Unfortunately they are not. I'm caching for 10 minutes at a time, which illustrates the speed at which they are changing.

Comment: Can the images be represented some other way like via SVG?

Comment: @Jason Sperske: They are user-uploaded photos, jpegs.

Answer (score 2):

Loading 100 images in one page request increases the page load time as each image requires time to load in browser.

simple technique is to load only one default image , means the source of each 100 image should be common default image and only one image wont take much time to load.

when page loads all of its content then try to load each single image with help jQuery.

use lazyload jQuery plugin to load all images after page load.

like this

```
<img class="lazy" src="default.jpg" data-original="img1.jpg" >
<img class="lazy" src="default.jpg" data-original="img2.jpg" >
<img class="lazy" src="default.jpg" data-original="img3.jpg" >
.......
<img class="lazy" src="default.jpg" data-original="img100.jpg">
```

and in script use following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
```

You may add expires header to each image which allows browser to cache them rather requesting them on next request.

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can always combine the images into a single image and use CSS to display only parts of it at a time (commonly called CSS sprites)

Google also has a rather in depth article about how they implemented "Instant Previews" that covers some of the optimizations:

http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/instant-previews-under-hood.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks, but in this case the images are requested through the db and are generally "dynamic" in the application. Spriting is not an option.

Comment: @Oded - Sure. However in this case the images themselves link to further content, they are editable by users, and users manipulate the order in which they are served. I think I'd be inviting more headache than I'm trying to solve in the first instance if I went down that route.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different domain for images - these will be called on different threads than for the current domain.

You can also host your images on a web server optimized to serve static content - this will be faster than a dynamic server.

The above can be extended to several such domains - if the browser is set to have 4 threads per domain, each domain you add will parallelize to an additional 4 (which is also one of the benefits of using a CDN).

Another common technique that *may* apply is the use of [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) - if you have a bunch of images that are commonly used together, you can put them all in a *single* image and use CSS to only show the bits that are needed where they are needed.